# Change multiple form fields based on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, css, cakephp

I'm creating a form for a property website (using CakePHP), which allows the user to search for specific properties.. I have two radio buttons with the options: 'commercial' and 'residential'

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('channel',
  array(
    'before' => '<label data-channel="commercial" . ($this->request->query('channel') != 'commercial' ? ' active' : '') . '">',
    'after' => '</label>',
    'separator' => '</label><label data-channel="residential" . ($this->request->query('channel') == 'commercial' ? ' active' : '') . '">',
    'options' => array(
        'commercial' => 'Commercial',
        'residential' => 'Residential'
    ),
    'type' => 'radio',
    'hiddenField' => false,
    'value' => $this->request->query('channel') == 'residential' ? 'residential' : 'commercial'
)
);?>
```

Commercial is selected by default and shows the following fields: location, type, size and rent.

When residential is selected, I want to hide: type, size and rent and then show: beds.

Essentially I would like to show / hide different form fields based on the 'on click' radio selection of residential or commercial

Comment: can you provide generated html

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do has to be done in the javascript side.

Firstly you want to add an `id` to your input fields so you can select them easily in javascript

Then do something like this:

```
radioInput.change( function() {
    if (this.val() == 'residential') {
         typeInput().hide();
         sizeInput().hide();
         rentInput().hide();
         bedsInput().show();
    } else {
         typeInput().show();
         sizeInput().show();
         rentInput().show();
         bedsInput().hide();
    }
});
```

NB: This is just a sketch, of what you have to do, and assumes you are using JQuery. You still have to get the inputs fields `radioInput = $('#radioInput');`, make sure to only show the appropriate fields initially, etc...

Hope this is enough to steer you in the right direction.